# What is a good algebra book to learn about logarithms?

Tags: logarithms

I want to learn the basics of logarithms. I am not sure where to look.
Can someone recommend a good algebra book to learn about logarithms?

Comment: real analysis textbooks cover the class of exponential functions and their inverses - logarithms. I don't understand what level text you are looking for. Is it something like W. Rudin's level of handling real analysis or more-so intuitive explanations such as KhanAcademy provides on youtube.

Comment: Any math textbook of the appropriate high school year (might vary depending on the country), I guess. Look for one with a lot of exercises.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions . I am looking for a book with logarithm basics .Like a dummies version book :-)

Comment: I don't personally know of any  bright examples in English, but some googling yields http://www.mathlogarithms.com/ They offer the book for free as a PDF-file.

Comment: are you indian?

Comment: Priyanka Vithani , yes :-)

Comment: I always liked the old editions (2nd and 3rd, say) of Fleming and Varberg's _College Algebra_.  Like most textbooks, successive editions got sillier and fatter.  They're just comic books now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , i have gone through a lot of text books but none of those has a noob friendly introduction to logarithms .Let me see if i can get a copy of this book .You are right about most of the books i get looks like comic books these days

Comment: If you're just getting started with logarithms, here is a tip that made everything easier for me: in an expression like $5^3$, the whole thing is called a power, the large number is the base, and the small number is called the exponent. In the expression $\log_5(125)$, exactly the same three roles appear: the small number is the base, the number in the brackets is the power and the whole expression is the exponent. For instance, $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$ and $\log_a(xy)=\log_a(x)+\log_a(y)$ are really the same thing: If bases are the same, then multiplying powers corresponds to adding exponents.

Comment: Have you tried reading the wiki page on logarithms?  It looks like it starts pretty basic.

Comment: Arthur , Thanks a lot for the tips .I will try the wikipedia page too :)